# A question about the Renewal Process (the expected value of the log of a product of IID).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, renewal-processes

I am studying stochastic processes with the textbook written by Robert G. Gallager. Due to my short knowledge, I have been faced with some difficulties to solve....

**Question**: A town starts a mosquito control program and the rv $Z_{n}$ is the number of mosquitoes at the end of the $n$ th year $(n=0,1,2, \ldots) .$ Let $X_{n}$ be the growth rate of the mosquito population in year $n ;$ i.e., $Z_{n}=X_{n} Z_{n-1} ; n \geq 1 .$ Assume that $\left\{X_{n} ; n \geq 1\right\}$ is a sequence of IID rv s with the $\operatorname{PMF} \operatorname{Pr}\{X=2\}=1 / 2 ; \operatorname{Pr}\{X=1 / 2\}=1 / 4 ; \operatorname{Pr}\{X=1 / 4\}=$
$1 / 4 .$ Suppose that $Z_{0},$ the initial number of mosquitoes, is some known constant and assume for simplicity and consistency that $Z_{n}$ can take on non-integer values.

(a) Find $E\left[Z_{n}\right]$ as a function of $n$ and find $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} E\left[Z_{n}\right]$.

(b) Let $W_{n}=\log _{2} X_{n} .$ Find $\mathrm{E}\left[W_{n}\right]$ and $\mathrm{E}\left[\log _{2}\left(Z_{n} / \mathrm{Z}_{0}\right)\right]$ as a function of $n$

(c) There is a constant $\alpha$ such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(1 / n)\left[\log _{2}\left(Z_{n} / Z_{0}\right)\right]=\alpha$ WP1. Find $\alpha$ and
explain how this follows from the SLLN.

(d) Using (c), show that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} Z_{n}=\beta$ WP1 for some $\beta$ and evaluate $\beta$.

(e) Explain carefully how the result in (a) and the result in (d) are compatible. What you should learn from this problem is that the expected value of the log of a product of IID rv s might be more significant than the expected value of the product itself.

I don't know how to answer the question (e). The result I calculated is $E\left(z_{n}\right)=z_{0}\left(\frac{19}{16}\right)^{n}$ from (a). The result of (d) is $\beta=Z_{0}$.

Comment: What is $WP_1$? converges a.s.?

Comment: @balaji "With probability $1$" - indeed, the same as "almost surely."

Comment: Since $Z_n=X_nZ_{n-1}$, we have $\frac{Z_n}{Z_0}=\frac1{Z_0}\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, from which the result holds.